# Pyspark Improve Repetitive Function Calls When Returning Dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, pyspark, automation

I have a multiple dataframes that I need to apply different functions to and I want to know if there is a way better way to do this in pyspark ?

I am doing the following right now:

```
df1 = function_one(df1)
df2 = function_one(df2)
df3 = function_one(df3)
df1 = function_two(df1, dfx, 0)
df2 = function_two(df2, dfx, 1)
df3 = function_two(df3, dfx, 2)
```

I have tried this:

```
list_dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
num_list = [0,1,2]
for dataframe,num in zip(list_dfs,num_list):
     dataframe = function(dataframe)
     dataframe  = function_two(dataframe , dfx, num)
```

This does not apply the changes.
Is there a way I can maybe do a loop in pyspark and apply the function to the multiple dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

This is just something I wrote quickly (not tested)
Just a suggestion, not sure if it's more convenient than what you're doing already (obviously it is if you have more dfs)

```
def make_changes(df):
   df = func(df)
   df = func2(df)
   return df

new_df_list = []
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
for dfs in df_list:
   new_df_list.append(make_changes(dfs))
```

Comment: The looks seem great! The second function in my case has a third argument that is incremental for each dataframe, how would I go about implementing this for your solution proposal?